# form_for creates the wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a form that should post to `/users/:user_id/user_languages`
The form view looks like this:
`form_for user_user_languages_url(@user) do |f|`

But when I render the page and inspect the form, the URL it uses is like this. How can that be? :-(

rake routes

```
     user_user_languages GET    /users/:user_id/user_languages(.:format)                       user_languages#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/user_languages(.:format)                       user_languages#create
```

Comment: `user_user_languages_path(@user)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to provide `user_id` to your helper:

```
form_for user_user_languages_url(user_id: @user.id)
```

By default, URL helper will set `id` parameter from the provided object. But you need `user_id` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :-D